# API design change best practice

Tags: java, api, design-patterns

I ran into a situation where I needed to change my API, needed to know the best option I have:
Initially my API stated:

```
DFS dfs = new DFS(Graph);
dfs.runDFS(source);
```

Now, I added another function to my DFS code, to return dfs path from input vertex to source.
Thus my new clean API looks like:

```
DFS dfs = new DFS(Graph, source); // BREAKS THE CONTRACT.
dfs.runDFS();                     // BREAKS THE CONTRACT.
dfs.getPathFromSource(vertex);
```

If I do maintain backward compatibility (maintain 2 constructors and 2 runDFS functions ) my clients would run into another problem:

```
 DFS dfs = new DFS(Graph);
 dfs.runDFS();                    
 dfs.getPathFromSource(vertex);
```

Although backward compatible, there is a bug, coz source is not mentioned anywhere(neither in constructor nor in function call).

Please suggest best API practice int this scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what `DFS` does and if it is meaningful to operate with or without a `source`. Generally speaking you should break your API only if there is no other option or if it has evolved to a point that a re-design is required anyway.

In this case the changes do not seem to be major ones (at least this is what I get from your description) so you could try to satisfy the old and the new client codebase at once (see an example below).

If you think it is appropriate you could even mark the old constructor and the old version of `runDFS` as `deprecated` and gradually remove them in the future.

```
public class DFS {

    public DFS(Graph graph) { ... }   // you have the option to mark this as deprecated 
    public DFS(Graph graph, Source source) { ... }  // New constructor

    public void runDFS() {    // New API
        if (this.source == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Source is null!");
        }
        doRun(this.source);
    }

    // Again you have the option to mark this as deprecated
    public void runDFS(Source source) {
        // handle here the case where client already provided a source with the new 
        // constructor. Should we replace it? Should we throw an exception?
        this.source = source;
        doRun(source);
    }

    private void doRun(Source source) {
        // this is private so it can be called by both runDFS() and runDFS(Source)
        // do whatever you did before here
    }

    public Path getPathFromSource(Vertex vertex) {   // New API
        if (source == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Source is null!");
        }
        // do the job for the new API here      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) design pattern, so you can separate the traversal of the graph from processing the nodes.

```
public interface NodeVisitor {
    public void visit(GraphNode node);
}
```

You need an implementation which will do the path calculation:

```
public class PathCalculatingVisitor implements NodeVisitor {
    public PathCalculatingVisitor(GraphNode target) {
          // source will be the start of the traversal
    }

    public void visit(GraphNode node) {
        // implement path calculation logic
    }

}
```

Your DFS class should accept an instance of this:

```
 // overloads runDFS(GraphNode source)
 public void runDFS(GraphNode source, NodeVisitor visitor) {
    // do traversing, then
    visitor.visit(node);
 }
```

Finally, the usage:

```
PathCalculatingVisitor pathCalculatingVisitor = new PathCalculatingVisitor(target);
DFS dfs = new DFS(graph);
dfs.runDFS(source, pathCalculatingVisitor);
pathCalculatingVisitor.getPath();
```

I think this design is more future proof, you will be able to add more visitors if needed without touching the DFS class, so this adheres to the [open-closed design principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain backward compatability at the cost of delayed production of the error:

In v1, it would be a compile time error to call `runDFS()` but in v2 w/ backwards compatability, you don't get an error until run time when the call is made to `runDFS()` and it determines the `source` wasn't provided by the constructor.

The goes for the new method, it fails if no `source` is provided by the constructor.

Without a `source` in the constructor, only the call to `runDFS(source)` works.

**Idea 2**

You could also create a totally new API by subclassing:

```
public class DFS2 extends DFS {
    private Object mySource;

    public DFS2(Graph g) {
        super(g);
    }

    public DFS2(Graph g, Object source) {
        mySource = source;
    }

    public void runDFS() {
        super.runDFS(mySource);
    }

    public Path getPathFromSource(Vertex vertex) {
        .... code goes here ...
    }

}
```

And DFS2 gets the new API. Old code still uses the old one and you share the bulk of the code itself.

```
DFS2 dfs = new DFS2(Graph, source);
dfs.runDFS();                     
dfs.getPathFromSource(vertex);
```